# Deserialize json containing csv file as response

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I get the following response

```
{
    "url": "https://XXX/plugins/servlet/export/exportAttachment?fileName=Cycle-SPRINT+19.csv"
}
```

I am using this class

```
public class csvBody
{
    public string url { get; set; }    
}
```

and the following code

```
WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
Stream newStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);
String resJson = sr.ReadToEnd();

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, csvBody>>(resJson);
```

But getting the following error

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value
>   "https://xxx/plugins/servlet/export/exportAttachment?fileName=Cycle-SPRINT+19.csv"
>   to type 'ReadCSV.csvBody'. Path 'url', line 1, position 101.'

Please let me know the correct way to deserialize this json response.

Comment: kindly provide the JSON result example to help you for building your object.

Comment: Why are you creating `Dictionary`? `var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<csvBody>(json);` will work for you.

Comment: The JSON response is at the beginning of the question

Comment: I am creating the Dictionary in order to be able to iterate. If it is var then how do i iterate ?

Comment: Why you need to iterate a single string variable in your csvbody class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of creating `Dictionary<string, csvBody>`. I tested with same json string and following solution will work for you.

You can access `url` using `dict.url`.

**Important thing is that API is only returning path of CSV file not content.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{ \"url\": \"https://XXX/plugins/servlet/export/exportAttachment?fileName=Cycle-SPRINT+19.csv\" }";

     var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<csvBody>(json);

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: @mach Kindly mark as answer / upvote if it is useful. Cheers :)